# How to hydrate a Doctrine entity using multiple connections

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I'm working with a legacy database that I cannot alter, and want to compose an entity that cannot be mapped in the standard way (YAML) because the related entities use a different database to the main entity.

As far as I can see, neither creating a custom hydration method nor encapsulating the logic in a repository will work, as both assume you are operating "within" a specific Entity Manager (and will be using the same connection for each entity as a result). I'm currently working around the problem with a private `hydrateResult()` method on a Controller, but I'm *really* unhappy about doing it this way.

Does anyone have any bright ideas? It feels like this sort of problem is exactly the sort of thing an ORM should help to solve, rather than exacerbate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your schemas run on the same database server then you can join across multiple schemas by including the schema name as part of the table name during your mapping:

```
Cerad\Bundle\AccountBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    table: schema1.account_user

Cerad\Bundle\AccountBundle\Entity\SomeName:
    type:  entity
    table: schema2.some_name
```

It's not a very good solution because it breaks most of the doctrine:schema commands.  But the queries will work.

If you have multiple servers then this won't work since sql simply does not support querying across multiple servers.  And there is nothing an ORM can really do about that.

Your best bet is to just bite the bullet and accept that you need two entity managers and that an extra query and a bit of logic will be required to link between the two.  This is actually quite common in the land of Domain Driven Design.  Might even turn out to be an advantage in the long run.

=============================================

One more possibility I forgot to mention and it might even qualify a bright idea.  You might be able to create a sql view that joins your tables.  You could then map a doctrine entity to that view.  Views have their own set of limitations so you may or may not be able to solve your problems with them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should've been clearer (sorry) - I already have multiple (3) entity managers, each with their own connection. I'm essentially trying to make this work as per your second suggestion... I guess my question is more, where can I put this logic if not in a Hydrator or Repository?

Comment: Also - I cannot use the database / table name hack unfortunately; our infrastructure is too complex and dependencies of that nature are a no-no! :)

Comment: Make yourself a service and inject all three entity managers into it.  Think of it as sort of a super entity manager.

Comment: Hmmm, that might be the way to go. I'll give it a try tomorrow